# Debugging a Streamlit application in PyCharm on Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, streamlit

I'm trying to setup a way to debug a `Streamlit` script in PyCharm. I'm on a Win10/64bit machine, working within an virtual environment created with conda.
Running the code in the default way with `streamlit run main.py` works as expected.
I have already read several forum posts and most importantly [this related question on SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60172282/how-to-run-debug-a-streamlit-application-from-an-ide).

My question is the following:
The answer in the question above suggests to change the debug configuration to use `Module name` instead of `Script path` and enter streamlit.cli as module. Then in the parameters one should set `run main.py` as the argument.

Unfortunately this gets me the following error:

> No module named streamlit.cli

Where do I find `streamlit.cli` shouldn't it be installed along with the default pip install of the library? Do I need to install it separately?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stumbled across the (rather simple) answer by accident:

Simply use the "correct" module name, which in my case was `streamlit` instead of `streamlit.cli`.
So for debugging I now have the following configuration:

- Module Name (instead of "Script path"): `streamlit`
- Parameter: `run main.py`
- Interpreter options: not set
- Working directory: <path\to\main.py>

As I have read in some streamlit forum post: "Works like a (Py)Charm!" :)

Comment: Indeed, it works like a (Py)Charm!

Comment: This answer was really helpful for debugging a streamlit project using PyCharm.

Comment: Does this method still work for the latest PyCharm? (I think it stopped working since 2023.3.x maybe. Definitely doesn't work in 2023.3.4). Error is `TypeError("'Task' object is not callable"`

Comment: @HHest tbh I am not sure, I have since moved completely to VSCode. In case it doesn't work anymore, maybe create a new post or if you find an updated solution, add an answer here.